# Using Apache CXF in from MATLAB

Tags: matlab, soap, cxf

The function [createClassFromWsdl](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/createclassfromwsdl.html) in MATLAB has some significant limitations, like not supporting attributes. It seems to me that the ability of Apache CXF to generate [dynamic clients](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/dynamic-clients.html) could be a way to access a wider variety of SOAP endpoints in a relatively user-friendly way. Simply adding the appropriate JAR files to your MATLAB classpath would allow you to interactively create robust clients from the MATLAB command line. Has anyone tried this? Would someone please provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

`createclassfromwsdl` has really limited functionality. Therefore I tried two java packages for SOAP communication from Matlab.

- Apache CXF - there were some problems during compilation and therefore I used the second alternative:
- Axis2: this worked quite well from Matlab, I performed following steps:

1)Install Axis2-1.5.4

2) `./wsdl2java.sh -uri http://webservice:port.. -o outfolder -uw`

3) Then I had to fix the generated stubs in order to avoid some errors during soap communication (you might not need it): 
- replace occurence of `SOAP12Constants` by `SOAP11Constants`

4)copile the sources in output folder using ant

5)Then in Matlab I use the following initialization procedure (assuming that the package.jar is in matlabpath and package is located in folder_foo)

```
if isempty(strfind(javaclasspath,'package.jar')) % check whether the jar package is already in javapath
r = matlabpath;
tokens = strtok(r,pathsep);
found = 0;
[p, remain] = strtok(r,pathsep);
while p
    if not(isempty(regexp(p, 'folder_foo', 'ignorecase')))
        javaaddpath([ p filesep 'package.jar'] ); % add to dynamic java path
        import eu.package.name; 
        h = StubConstructor(); %instantiate the object
        found = 1;
        break;
    end
    p = strtok(remain,r);
end
if not(found)
    error('WS client initialization failed')
end
end
```